# Connect Amazon WorkMail with another Email Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, gmail, amazon-workmail

I have an AWS WorkMail Organization with some users. My goal *(not sure if it is possible)* is to use the Gmail Application (or any other email provider) instead of Amazon WorkMail App for sending and receiving emails.

I basically want to use Gmail as the interface backed by WorkMail

[image]

My main reasons are, that I (1) prefer the Gmail / ProtonMail interface and (2) want to use the Gmail mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not because WorkMail doesn't support POP according to January 2019. Shame to AWS [image]

Answer (score 0):

As Gmail app works with Exchange server, you can add WorkMail account to your Gmail app.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/mobile-start.html